# Enable default right click on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, web, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to enable the Chrome's default right click context menu in sites that overrides it creating their own context menu? (Google applications, Youtube...)

I find it very useful to be able to right click to inspect the element rather than having to go to F12, select the magnifying glass and find the element I want to inspect.

I've been checking some Chrome extension such as:

- [RightToCopy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/righttocopy/plmcimdddlobkphnofejmeidjblideca)
- [Enable right click](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enable-right-click/hhojmcideegachlhfgfdhailpfhgknjm)
- [Right-Click enabler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/right-click-enabler/fmmfnoikodocoelbimkedjdiaoejbddd)

None of them seem to work in a basic example such as [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/68qkbtLa/).

```
//context menu for orders table
$(document).on("contextmenu", "body", function (event) {
    //we won't show the default context menu
    event.preventDefault();

    $('#menu').dropdown('toggle')

    //showing it close to our cursor
    $('#menu').dropdown('toggle').css({
        top: (event.pageY) + "px",
        left: (event.pageX) + "px"
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe it's only possible to clear the event handlers attached with jQuery: `delete $._data(document, "events").contextmenu`. This must be executed in the webpage context of course by injecting the code [as page script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/3959875)

Comment: Enable right click works for me on that demo.

Comment: It works for me on the second right-click.  I would sacrifice my first born for an extension that does this perfectly.

Comment: Tested it on the site that made me come here, which is an implementation of Drupal using CKE, and it doesn't work at all.  :(